# Extract a value out of n

Tags: python, list

How do you extract a value out of **n** of a list in python ?

For example :

```
n = 3
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And I would like to get

```
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

I know I can do this with a `for`, but is there any more *pythonic* and short way ?

Comment: And what does `n` *mean* here. Divisible by `n`? Every nth value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple list comprehension

```
>>> n = 3
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [i for i in l if i%n==0]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

If your list is always like that, then you can use strides

```
>>> l[::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

**Tip**

Use `range` to generate lists like that

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know any good reference about python, because these strides were not mentioned, neither in my lectures nor in the reference I use?

Comment: @servabat Strides are not usually covered. (They did appear in my exam as an Out of Syllabus question). The python docs are the best way to learn python. Go through them, It might take a few days, but it is the best material .... :)

Comment: Thank you! Python is definitely more popular than I thought.

Comment: @servabat You are welcome bro.... All the best in your encounters with Python ... May the gods of python be with you

Answer (score 0):

Using *slicing* would be the most pythonic way:

```
In [1]: n = 3

In [2]: l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: l[::n]
Out[3]: [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a slice with stride:

```
l[::n]
```

Demo:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[::n]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print l[::3] # slice with step n = 3
```